# Asignar evento onclick de plugin Popup Anything a Button Advanced de Visual Composer

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quería ver si es posible que me ayudaran a resolver lo siguiente.
Tengo instalado el plugin Popup Anything que genera el siguiente código:

```
<a class="paoc-popup popupaoc-button" href="javascript:void(0);" data-conf="{"content":{ "target" : "#paoc-modal-1", "effect": "blur", "positionX": "center", "positionY": "center", "fullscreen": false, "speedIn": 300, "speedOut": 300, "delay": 150},"loader":{"active": true},"overlay":{"active": true}}">Click me</a>
```

Y que responde al siguiente evento:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://localhost/itsolnic/wp-content/plugins/popup-anything-on-click/assets/js/popupaoc-popup.min.js?ver=1.4.2'></script>

<div id="paoc-modal-1" class="paoc-popup-modal">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="Custombox.modal.close();" class="paoc-popup-close"></a>       
    <div class="paoc-popup-modal-cnt">
        <p>Prueba de popup</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="paoc-modal-2" class="paoc-popup-modal">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="Custombox.modal.close();" class="paoc-popup-close"></a>       
    <div class="paoc-popup-modal-cnt">
        <p>Test # 2</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery(document).on('click', '.paoc-popup', function() {
            var options = jQuery(this).data('conf');
            new Custombox.modal(options).open();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Mi pregunta es, cómo puedo asignar ese evento a un Button Advanced de Visual Composer con el siguiente código:

```
<button class="vc_general vc_btn3 vc_btn3-size-md vc_btn3-shape-rounded vc_btn3-style-modern vc_btn3-color-pink">Click me</button>
```

El botón permite insertar código para el evento click. Pero lo que he intentado no me ha funcionado :(

De antemano muchas gracias por cualquier ayuda.

Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Logré hacerlo y les comparto la solución para aquellos que les pueda servir.

El siguiente método abre una nueva ventana modal:

```
new Custombox.modal({}).open();
```

Dentro de los corchetes o llaves, agregamos los parámetros de la misma, donde también se incluye el ID de la ventana modal a abrir, en mi ejemplo los parámetros son:

```
"content":{ "target" : "#paoc-modal-1", "effect": "blur", "positionX": "center", "positionY": "center", "fullscreen": false, "speedIn": 300, "speedOut": 300, "delay": 150},"loader":{"active": true},"overlay":{"active": true}
```

Dejo el código:

```
new Custombox.modal({
   "content":{
      "target":"#paoc-modal-1",
      "effect":"blur",
      "positionX":"center",
      "positionY":"center",
      "fullscreen":false,
      "speedIn":300,
      "speedOut":300,
      "delay":150
   },
   "loader":{
      "active":true
   },
   "overlay":{
      "active":true
   }
}).open();
```

Y listo, ya me abre la ventana modal desde el evento click del botón de Visual Composer.

Saludos.